# Segmentation fault in array for max index difference problem

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, indexing, segmentation-fault

I wrote this c++ function to find the maximum index difference in an array given that arr[i]<=arr[j] this runs fine with the given test cases but when i submit the code it shows segmentation fault

constrains :-
1 ≤ T ≤ 1000
1 ≤ N ≤ 10^7
0 ≤ A[i] ≤ 10^18

```
    long long maxIndexDiff(int  arr[], int n) 
{ 
    
    // Your code here
    vector<long long  > num;
    for(long i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        num.push_back(arr[i]);
    }
    long high =n-1;
    long low=0;
    long i_index,j_index;
    while(low<high)
    {
        if(num[high]>=num[low])
        {
            i_index=low;
            j_index=high;
            break;
        }
         
        low++;
        high--;
    }
    
   for(long i=j_index;i<n;i++)
   {
       if(num[i]>=num[i_index])
       j_index=i;
   }
   
   for(long i=i_index;i>=0;i--)
   {
       if(num[i]<=num[j_index])
       i_index=i;
   }
    
    return (j_index-i_index);
}
```

Comment: did you try running it with debugger?

Comment: You are probably accessing `num` out-of-bounds.

Comment: no i didnt try debugger , how to fix out of bound error? even if i remove vector and work with array it shows segmentation fault

Comment: You made the problem worse by using an array.  Just use `vector::at()` instead of `[ ]` when accessing the elements in the vector.  One of those `at()` calls will throw an `std::out_of_range` exception if the value is out-of-bounds.

Comment: if  you didn't use a debugger its a good operonety to learn how to use one

Comment: this question had driver code hence i cannot make any modification to function arguments , i got my error it wont run for an decreasing array elements or a single element thats why it always had segmentation fault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not work properly for `N=1`, because in this case the `while(low<high)` loop will be finished without a single iteration and both `i_index` and `j_index` will stay unitialized.

Comment: thanks , yesterday only i found that mistake in my code